# ros cross-compile for gumstix?

Tags: ros, gumstix, cross-compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

does anyone know of instructions on how to setup cross-compilation of ros packages for gumstix (or any ARM processor). I only see instructions on how to compile ROS itself. I am more interested in packages I can compile on a host computer (faster), so then I can just move the binary file into the gumstix and run it!

Note:both the host and the gumstix are running ubuntu, gumstix is already running gumros.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10281/ros-cross-compile-for-gumstix?/) by [prasenjit](https://answers.ros.org/users/700/prasenjit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See "eros"

http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros

---

Originally posted by [Straszheim](https://answers.ros.org/users/44/straszheim/) with karma: 426 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1